# Incorrect cron for midnight?

Tags: cron

I checked the `crontab` set by the hosting company and they have this:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/php /www/sites/[domain.com]/files/html/shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

Does this `cron` run constantly or once at midnight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

midnight is

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /www/sites/[domain.com]/files/html/shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

your current crontab runs every full hour. For more info see e.g. [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)